# SQL Join over 3 tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to pull data from two tables based on another.

So.. I've these tables:

```
 **tblCategory**
 CategoryID, CategoryName

 **tblProdCat**
 prodCatID, productID, categoryID

 **tblProducts**
 productID, description, price
```

I need to join the tables and locate information from tblProdCat and tblProducts with only the CategoryName available to me.

```
   SELECT tblProducts.name, 
                       tblProducts.description, 
                       tblProducts.price, 
                       tblProducts.qtyInStock, 
                       tblProducts.image,
                       tblProducts.colour,
                       tblProducts.size,
                       tblProducts.style,
                       tblProdCat.prodCatID   
                  FROM
                        tblProducts, tblProdCat,tblCategory 
                  WHERE tblCategory.categoryName='Pens' 
                  AND   tblProdCat.categoryID = tblProducts.categoryID
```

I've tried the above and also tried other joins but an pulling my hair out.  I've read tutorials and just do not understand how a join works.  Can anybody help?  Please..

Comment: Do you want for items and product categories to appear as separate rows in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the following `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT p.name, 
  p.description, 
  p.price, 
  p.qtyInStock, 
  p.image,
  p.colour,
  p.size,
  p.style,
  pc.prodCatID,
  c.CategoryName
FROM tblProducts p
INNER JOIN tblProdCat pc 
  ON p.productID = pc.productID
INNER JOIN tblCategory c
  ON pc.categoryID = c.categoryID
WHERE c.categoryName='Pens'
```

I used an `INNER JOIN` between each table which will return all rows that match between each table.

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Now, if you wanted to return all `Products` whether or not it has a category, then you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.name, 
  p.description, 
  p.price, 
  p.qtyInStock, 
  p.image,
  p.colour,
  p.size,
  p.style,
  pc.prodCatID,
  c.CategoryName
FROM tblProducts p
LEFT JOIN tblProdCat pc 
  ON p.productID = pc.productID
LEFT JOIN tblCategory c
  ON pc.categoryID = c.categoryID
  AND c.categoryName='Pens'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper syntax for an Inner join which will keep only the records with matching rows category Ids.

```
 SELECT tblProducts.name, 
    tblProducts.description, 
    tblProducts.price, 
    tblProducts.qtyInStock, 
    tblProducts.image,
    tblProducts.colour,
    tblProducts.size,
    tblProducts.style,
    tblProdCat.prodCatID 

  FROM tblProducts
  INNER JOIN tblProdCat ON tblProdCat.productId= tblProducts.productId
  INNER JOIN tblCategory ON tblCategory ON tblCategory.categoryId = tblProdCat.categoryId
  WHERE tblCategory.categoryName='Pens'
```

If some category Ids can be missing and you want those rows then it's prudent to do a LEFT JOIN:

```
 SELECT tblProducts.name, 
    tblProducts.description, 
    tblProducts.price, 
    tblProducts.qtyInStock, 
    tblProducts.image,
    tblProducts.colour,
    tblProducts.size,
    tblProducts.style,
    tblProdCat.prodCatID 

  FROM tblProducts
  LEFT JOIN tblProdCat ON tblProdCat.productId= tblProducts.productId
  LEFT JOIN tblCategory ON tblCategory ON tblCategory.categoryId = tblProdCat.categoryId
  WHERE tblCategory.categoryName='Pens'
```

This will return all records from tblProducts regardless of the presence of corresponding records in the other two tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
You missed to add one more condition.    
 SELECT tblProducts.name, 
                           tblProducts.description, 
                           tblProducts.price, 
                           tblProducts.qtyInStock, 
                           tblProducts.image,
                           tblProducts.colour,
                           tblProducts.size,
                           tblProducts.style,
                           tblProdCat.prodCatID   
                      FROM
                           tblProducts, tblProdCat,tblCategory 
                      WHERE 
                            tblCategory.categoryName='Pens' 
                      **AND   tblProdCat.categoryID = tblCategory.categoryID
                      AND   tblProducts.productID = tblProdCat.productID**
```